# HTML headers and footers: edit multiple files from one place

Tags: html, css, file, ide, edit

I am currently coding up my own website (basically a personal blog) w/ HTML5 and CSS3. However, the growing number of .html files (blog posts and other stuff) quickly raised a problem: say if I want to change something in my page header / footer (which I want to keep the same across the entire site), I would have to edit every .html file to get this done. Is there anyway that this process can be simplified to a one-time action? Mostly, I write html files in Brackets. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are going to have to enter the world of frontend environment tooling. Start to look at gulp or Webpack and start to look into HTML templating. Read up on  .kit, handlebars, nunjucks, ejs, pug

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the files as .php, create another file for the header and footer, and include the header and footer `( <?php include 'header.php'; ?> )` files from each of the main files?

Comment: Thanks! Are you saying I could write this one .php file which just echoes out the entire html code for my header & footer? I tried embedding this file in my html, but every time I would get a `php warning: Cannot modify header information`